# Резко замедлилась скорость отправки писем с сайта(ubuntu, php, sendmail)

Tags: php, ubuntu, администрирование, sendmail, рассылка

Имеется сайт(`Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS`), `nginx+php-fpm`, выделенный сервер.
С него еженедельно идет рассылка подборки материалов пользователям (скрипт на `php`, очередь в `Mysql`, рассыльщик `sendmail`).

Суть проблемы: резко замедлилась скорость отправки писем. Ранее рассылка вполне ненапряжно уходила за 4 часа, сейчас - порядка 20. Никаких работ на сайте и сервере в это время не производилось. В остальном никаких видимых изменений в работе нет, видимых тормозов также не наблюдалось.
Конфиги не прикладываю, так как просадка произошла не в результате их изменения.

В каком направлении можно начать копать?
В первую очередь - действительно ли проблема в рассыльщике или в каких-то смежных вещах, к примеру `dns`, или забитости канала, или тупо перегруженности базы и/или свободной памяти, или аппаратно сети или диска, или вообще какой-то левый скрипт отжирает ресурсы?
Какие средства диагностики(учитывая что рабочий сервер) тут можно использовать?
Какие логи смотреть, как замерять скорости?

Comment: А что показывает top? Есть ли swap файл в системе? Не включали xdebug или другой отладчик?

Comment: top не показывал ничего особенного. за исключением 50% потребления памяти мускулом, но это в основном кеш и "особенности" работы крон скриптов. отладчиков не включено.

Comment: Mem:   3942744k total,  3547700k used,   395044k free,   139056k buffers
Swap:  4084732k total,   306432k used,  3778300k free,   924728k cached

Comment: Памяти мало осталось, меньше 10%, swap, похоже, активно используется. Это тормозит систему, но не в 5 раз. Я бы поджал память MySQL и php, чтобы swap был пуст. Посмотрите, что получится.

Comment: еще варианты? то есть памяти, конечно, для текущей ситуации недостаточно, но это скорее следствие а не причина. на php используется doctrine, что на память оказывает катастрофическое воздействие. Но, повторюсь, при той же конфигурации и скриптах 2 недели назад сабжевой проблемы не было.

Comment: непонятно, что именно у вас длилось 20 часов вместо четырёх — генерация или рассылка. если первое, то проблема, скорее всего — внутренняя. если рассылка, то, скорее всего — внешняя.

Answer (score 0):

Напишу в ответ, т.к. в комментарий не поместится. Ничего оригинального тут не будет, просто обозначу пару моментов.

Как я понял, все находится на одном сервере (и веб-сервер, и база данных и почтовик).

Первым делом я бы постарался сэмулировать эту рассылку в "/dev/null".
Не знаю как у вас это реализовано (запускается через движок сайта или отдельным скриптом в кроне), но смысл такой:

посмотреть на скорость формирования рассылки, исключив часть самой отправки писем, т.е. фактически исключив всю "сетевую" часть (smtp, dns resolve, etc). Думаю, что идея понятна и обсуждать тут техническую часть нет смысла.

По результатам этой эмуляции можно будет сделать некоторые выводы: время выполнения, загрузка CPU, утилизация CPU, потребление памяти.

Если результаты неудовлетворительные (рассылка формируется дольше предполагаемого времени), то, логично, остановиться на поиске узкого места между mysql и php. Если софт сервера не обновлялся, конфиги не менялись и т.д., очень вероятно, что mysql окажется узким местом. Тюнинг mysql-я - это отдельная тема, в один абзац не опишешь.

Если результаты "рассылки" удовлетворительные (рассылка укладывается в понятные временные интервалы), то переходим к "дебагу" SMTP. Но, к сожалению, это опять таки отдельная тема.